# number of documents vs size of documents in MongoDB

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-atlas

In terms of performance, is having 25 million small documents the same as having 100,000 documents with an array of 250 subdocuments?

(subdocuments would be the same as the 25M collection)

Comment: Depends on your needs, i.e. your main queries.